# What is causing PGError: ERROR: there is no parameter $1 in my Rails app

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rails-postgresql

[image]

I started getting this error on edit/show of a Rank object.  I've never seen it before and am not sure how to resolve it.  Any input?

Comment: Seems this is the offending line: has_scope :page, :default => 1.  Not sure what the issue is still, but removing that line causes the error to disappear.

Comment: Yes, using the has_scope gem.  I'm also using inherited_resources for the controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a PostgreSQL error. Check the SQL that your application is generating.