# scope causes error in Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

The following application **working fine with sqlite**.

### Book model

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :month, :pages, :title, :year, :author_attributes, :publisher_attributes

    belongs_to :author
    belongs_to :publisher

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :author
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :publisher
end
```

### Book controller

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
     respond_to(:html)

     expose(:books, :ancestor => [:author, :publisher]) { Book.scoped.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page=>params[:per_page])}
     expose(:book)
     # other functions here
end
```

with postgresql, it gives the following error when I tried to visit `http://localhost:3000/books/1`

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Books#show

Showing /Users/tunwinnaing/Projects/rails_projects/books/app/views/books/show.html.haml where line #1 raised:

PG::UndefinedParameter: ERROR:  there is no parameter $1    
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "books"  WHERE "books"."id" = $1    
                                                           ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "books"  WHERE "books"."id" = $1
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: - provide( :title, "#{book.title} | " )    
2: %h1= book.title    
3: %hr    
4: .row
```

#### Background information

- ruby 1.9.3
- rails 3.2.13
- decent_exposure 2.2.0
- will_paginate 3.0.3
- pg 0.16.0
- postgresql 9.x (using postgresapp)

#### Tried the following

- [What is causing PGError: ERROR: there is no parameter $1 in my Rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7123293) - I need `will_paginate` and couldn't remove the page
- if I removed the `Book.scoped.paginate` from `expose(books)`, it works but I do not know how to paginate without scope.
- I tried `prepared_statement: false` in `database.yml` and conclude that it has nothing to do with this error.

**What is the source of problem here?** And how could I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Kaminari`, the error no longer exists and I got the feature what I wanted.

Diving deeper into the inner working of `pg` or `will_paginate` might find the cause of the problem.